# Closing Threads in Executor Service without shutting it down

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My code for executor service is shown below. I am executing multiple threads. But for some reason the program is not exiting as there are some threads in waiting state according to the logs. If I use Thread.start(), then I don't have that problem. I am facing the problem only when I am using ExecutorService.Can anyone tell me how to close all the threads which executed successfully without shutting down ExecutorService.

```
class ExecutorExample{
    public static void main(){
        File folder = new File("/home/agasthyt/agasthyt");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            Thread1 thread1=new Thread1(listOfFiles[i]);
            es.execute(thread1);
    }
  }
}
```

class Thread1 extends Thread{public void run(){......}}

Comment: If you do not need the threads to return (which I think you do), you can set them as daemons.

Comment: No, it looks like `shutdown()` is required.  You'll have to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone show me how to close all the threads which executed successfully without shutting down ExecutorService.

That is not what `ExecutorService` is for.  When you create an ExecutorService, you give it *tasks* to perform, and you let *it* manage the threads that it uses to execute your task.  You aren't supposed to know or care about the threads that it uses.

When you don't want it anymore (e.g., when you want to terminate the program), then you shut it down.

---

P.S., Your `Thread1` class `extends Thread`.  That's a bad habit that leads you into a less-useful way of thinking about threads.  The right way to think about threads and executors is that a thread or an executor is just this thing that executes some piece or pieces of code that you give it.  Nothing more.

I've seen a lot of questions that say things like, "I need the X thread to do Y, but...", and what's leading them into trouble is that the developer has given the X thread too many *responsibilities*.

In a well-designed program, it should not matter *which* thread does Y.  Threads should be anonymous and interchangeable.

---

**Update:**

> Can you suggest any method to close the threads without shutting down executor service.

No, I can't.  If the threads were created by an ExecutorService, then it would be wrong for your program to kill those threads behind its back.

**Q:** What class are you using that implements `ExecutorService`?  Is it a `ThreadPoolExecutor` perhaps?  Perhaps you could solve your problem by creating a `ThreadFactory` that makes *daemon* threads, and then construct your `ThreadPoolExecutor` using that factory.  A daemon thread will not stop the program from exiting.

Comment: what you are saying is absolutely correct. This is just a sample program. There are few threads which go into waiting. hence the program doesn't exit. Can you suggest any method to close the threads without shutting down executor service as I need the same executor service for executing other threads.

Comment: If i call es.execute(), there is a small problem even after the thread completes its execution it is sent to waiting state. When I saw the stacktrace it is something like sun.misc.unsafe.park, that is why I needed to shut it down without closing executor service, as I am using it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Executors class that provides newFixedThreadPool method, so in this way you can select the max number of threads that you want to use.
Exceutors will use the same number of threads and will reuse the space if necessary. I attached the documentation

```
enter code hereint maxNumberOfThread=10;
ExecutorService pool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxNumberOfThread);
... 
pool.execute(new Thread1(listOfFiles[i]));
```

Documentation
[Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html),
[ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)